# Listbox AddItem Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am having problems getting a list box to work in VBA. I'm not sure what step I am missing.  I have created a listbox called ListBox1.

I wrote the program as follows:

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim ListBox As Object

    With Listbox1
        .AddItem = "Yes"
        .AddItem = "No"
    End With
End Sub
```

The program fails at the `.AddItem = "No"` line.  I get `Object Variable or With Block Variable not set` error.

Comment: You never set your listbox variable to an actual listbox object.  If you just use `With Listbox1` then Listbox1 needs to be on the active sheet or userform the code is on.  If the code is in a standard module, you need to specify the sheet or userform that contains the listbox: `With Sheets("Sheet1").Listbox1` or `With UserForm1.Listbox1`

Comment: Also, there is no `=` sign when using the `.Additem` method

Comment: the change event adds items to itself, thus activating a new change event. you need to add a boolean condition with a global variable wich will block events.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies!  I got it figured out.  I was mixing up the Form Control and Active X Control syntax.  Thanks for the helpful tips!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why are you adding items to the same Listbox in the change event. However there is a syntax error in your code. There is no `=` when you add an item to the listbox. See this.

```
With Listbox1
    .AddItem "Yes"
    .AddItem "No"
End With
```

Also remove the line `Dim ListBox as Object`. You do not need it.

If you are planning to add it to another listbox then I think you need this

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
    With ListBox2 '<~~ Replace this with the other listbox name
        .AddItem "Yes"
        .AddItem "No"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply!  I removed the equal sign.  I also referenced it with the correct worksheet and got rid of  Dim statement.  I was getting mixed up on how to write the code for the Form vs Active X, but I think I've got it all figured out now.  I see one has an output i.e. 1,2,3.  After tweaking it a bit, I find I like the Active X controls Better.  Thanks Again!